# App does not become the preferred MediaButtonReceiver when calling setActive(true) a second time

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I have tried to implement media button control per [Google's talk](https://youtu.be/XQwe30cZffg?t=20m21s)

I set the receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".player.PlayFileService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

create the `MediaSessionCompat` in `onCreate()` of Service:

```
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), "SOUNDPROCESS");
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    PlaybackStateCompat ps = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
            .build();
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(ps);
    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onPlay() { ...
           }
    });
```

and handle the intent in `onStartCommand()`

```
MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent);
```

I then call `setActive(true);` when I gain audio focus, and `setActive(false);` when I stop playback. This works the first time, my app becomes the preferred media button receiver and receives callbacks.

However, if I stop playback in my app, go into another app like Google Play Music and start playback there, then return to my app and call `setActive(true)` Google Play Music continues to receive the callback and the media buttons don't work in my app.

From my understanding, the last call to `setActive(true)` should take precedence. I have verified that `isActive()` returns true. I can also work around the issue by creating a new `MediaSessionCompat` each time, but this doesn't seem ideal.

How can I make my app become the preferred media button receiver every time I call `setActive(true)`?

UPDATE: Minimum project to reproduce the problem here: https://github.com/svenoaks/MediaButtonDemo.git

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run app, press the PLAY button. `setActive(true)` is called and
       MediaButtonReceiver is now the preferred media button.
2. Press play/pause button on wired or wireless headphones or other
   media button. Toast shows indicating that callback is working.
3. Start playback on another app such as Google Play Music which
   supports media buttons. Press pause on this app.
4. The demo app can no longer be the preferred media button receiver,
   even if PLAY button is pressed again, calling `setActive(true)`
   again. The other app always responds to media buttons.

This was tested on Android 6.0.

Comment: Is `MediaButtonReceiver` programmatically registered/unregistered or just manifest-defined? What does `MediaButtonReceiver`'s `onReceive()` do? Where do you call `setActive(true/false)` from?

Comment: It is defined in the manifest. It is the default implementation of onReceive(). setActive(true) is called when when from the service whenever audio focused is gained in the play() method. setActive(false) is called in the stop() method. Everything is per the linked video.

Comment: Also, what does `MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent)` do? Is it a static method?

Comment: It is a static method, it decodes the received intent and passes to your MediaSessionCompat callbacks.

Comment: @Onik demo project posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to making this work correctly is to correctly set the `PlaybackState` every time your app starts playing or pauses (which it should be doing when another app gains the audio session and activates its own `MediaSession`. Without this, the problem as above will happen. Also, for Android 4.4 and lower,  `FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS` must be set or the same problem will happen.

Answer (score 3):

My observations: (No enough reputations to comment, apologies, but I can reply to the comments for this answer)

1. 'Run app, press the PLAY button. setActive(true) is called and MediaButtonReceiver is now the preferred media button': because Android first dispatches media button events to the foreground activity.
2. 'Start playback on another app.......Press pause on this app........then return to my app and call setActive(true) ':

a) if you had called onStop listener before playing GooglePlay Music, then your media session is not active (until onPlay is called again) when you press any media button, and so the current session which is Google Play gets played.

b) If you hadn't called onStop then there are 2 active sessions (the first session of your app and the first session of Google Play. Second session won't be called unless OnPlay is called again). According to docs,  if there are multiple active media sessions, Android tries to choose a media session that is preparing to play (buffering/connecting), playing, or paused, rather than one that is stopped.' So GooglePlay is the latest active session with paused state and gets played.

c) If you had called onStop (thus setActive(false)), and if GooglePlayMusic had also setActive(false), and you haven't clicked onPlay again then in that case too GooglePlayMusic will be played since "If there is no active session, Android tries to send the event to the most recently active session. On Android 5.0 (API level 21) or later the event is only sent to sessions that have called setMediaButtonReceiver()."

Have you setMediaButtonReceiver()?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons.html
Kindly have a look at it

Comment: If 'Android tries to choose a media session that is preparing to play (buffering/connecting), playing, or paused, rather than one that is stopped.' maybe it is as simple as changing the PlayState.

Comment: Setting the playstate to PLAYING makes no difference, also it does not route to the foreground activity per the documentation. In short, once Google Play Music starts responding to media buttons there is no way to make my app respond again without creating a new MediaSessionCompat.

Comment: Have you used setMediaButtonReceiver()?

Comment: Yes, still no change.

Comment: maybe it will be better if you ask ianhanniballake http://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake